# NetBeans 6.8 for C does not recognize 'bool' (C/C++ noob)

Tags: c, netbeans, boolean, syntax-error

I'm currently working on an implementation of a doubly linked list (teaching myself c in preparation for the arrival of my rasp-pi!), and i'v encountered an odd error message. NetBeans doesn't seem to recognize the boolean data-type. What's strange is that i can implement booleans in both of the other classes in the project (main.c & dLinkedList.h). So far i've tried re-installing & updating cygwin (did not resolve the problem). I'll attach some screen shots below.

boolean test in main.c

[image]

boolean test in dLinkedList Header

[image]

boolean test in dLinkedList.c

[image]

Additionally, both my main.c and dLinkedList.c contain the following headers:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"dll.h"
```

Any insights would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: bool isn't C, it's C++

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Since you mention "for C" and your file has a `.c` extension, removing the C++ tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C99 you need to include `stdbool.h`, from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.16` *Boolean type and values*  says:

> 1 The header  defines four macros.
>
> 2 The macro
>
> bool
>
> expands to _Bool.

If C99 is not supported then you need to define your own bool, for example:

```
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C, include `stdbool.h` to get the `bool` macro. However this header only exists if you are using `C99` or greater.

Comment: Or define your own, perhaps via `typedef enum {false = 0, true = 1} bool;`

Comment: Great point. I've got such bad tunnel vision that i hadn't even considered implementing my own boolean. thanks a ton for your input!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in C you have three options:

Defines:

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

Enumerations:

```
typedef enum 
{ 
    false, 
    true 
}bool;
```

Add C99 header:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```